# Module Won't recognize my function

Tags: python, function, runtime-error, greatest-common-divisor

I have a code for a Fraction class

```
class Fraction:

    def __init__(self,top,bottom):  
        self.num = top  
        self.den = bottom  

    def __str__(self):  
        return str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den)  

    def show(self):  
        print(self.num,"/",self.den)  

    def gcd(m,n):  
        while m%n != 0:  
            oldm = m  
            oldn = n  
            m = oldn  
            n = oldm%oldn  
        return n  


    def __add__(self,otherfraction):  
        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den + \  
                     self.den*otherfraction.num  
        newden = self.den * otherfraction.den  
        common = gcd(newnum,newden)  
        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)  

    def __eq__(self, other):  
        firstnum = self.num * other.den  
        secondnum = other.num * self.den    
        return firstnum == secondnum
```

When I run it and try to add two fractions it pops up saying

```
File "/Users/----/Downloads/Listings/listing_1_9.py", line 25,  
 in __add__
    common = gcd(newnum,newden)  
NameError: global name 'gcd' is not defined
```

Comment: try self.gcd(newnum,newden)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `gcd` is a method of Fraction, so you should use `self.gcd` when referring to it from inside another method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `self.gcd` instead.

## Explanation

```
NameError: global name 'gcd' is not defined
```

Thats because gcd is not a global. Its a method of `Fraction`.